# Java Properties class for Android testing

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to create an Eclipse Android project which utilizes the Java Properties class. For the project, I have a config text file in my src directory which contains the key-value pairs. I also have a config class, which contains a properties object to be used for initially reading the config file as well as accessing the various properties throughout execution. However, I'm getting some errors when accessing some properties. I'd like to see the properties file I'm generating so that I can debug easier. How would I go about doing this?

```
public static Properties prop;

static {

    AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    InputStream instream = assetManager.open("config");
    readConfig(instream);

}

private static void readConfig(Inputstream instream) {

    try {
        String line = "";
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(instream);

        while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] split_line = line.split("=", 2);
            prop.setProperty(split_line[0], split_line[1]);
        }

        prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"), "Default and local config files");
        read.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("cool", "Failed to create properly initialize config class");
    }
}

public static String getProperty (String propertyKey) {

    try {
        return prop.getProperty(propertyKey);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("cool", "Failed to access property");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to read some key/value pairs from a text file then you should not put this text file in your src directory, that's what the assets directory is for. You can access all files in the assets directory through an Uri like this file:///android_asset/... or preferably you can use this code:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream instream = assetManager.open("file.txt");
```

EDIT: Try implementing your Config class like this:

```
public class Config
{
    private static Config instance;
    public static Config getInstance(Context context)
    {
         if(instance == null)
         {
             instance = new Config(context);
         }
         return instance;
    }

    protected Config(Context context)
    {
       AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
       ...
    }
}
```

You can then use your Config class in your code like this:

```
Config config = Config.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
config.getProperty(...);
```

Comment: So the way I'm reading this, I would use AssetManager instead of Properties. When using Properties, I load each key/value pair by calling setProperty. How do I go about doing this with the assetManager?

Basically what I have is a Config class that is static and initializes all the properties at run time. It then has a getProperty method in order to access each property value via its key. How would I use AssetManager to provide this functionality?

Comment: With AssetManager you can access files in the assets directory. But if you want to read key/value pairs from there I would still use the Properties class.

Comment: Properties class has a method called load(InputStream in) you can get the inputstream from your file using assetManager.open("config.txt"); and load the key/value pairs into your properties object.

Comment: Your above code doesn't seem to work, at least the getAssets method. I get that getAssets is undefined.

Comment: In what context are you trying to use it? You can call it in an Activity for example.

Comment: I have a static class called Config. The Config class has a static initialization block where I'm calling AssetManager asM = getAssets(); However, I'm being told that Config doesn't have a getAssets method. Should I write a getAssets method for config that gets the context? How else do I do this?

Comment: Just edited my submission to reflect the code I am using. I would prefer to have Config remain static as it prevents me from having to instantiate it throughout the code.

Comment: When you initialize your Config class you should give it the Context of your activity. Try building your Config class as Singleton.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with that at all. How would I go about doing that?